# Unable to test variable value with Wire in jest

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest, wire

I am trying to read simple users list with wire method. However, I'm unable to test the variable value in jest promise, is there anything wrong with my code/understanding?

LWC -

```js
@wire(getUsers)
  users;
```

Jest -

```js
import getUsers from "@salesforce/apex/UserUtil.getUsers";
import { registerLdsTestWireAdapter } from "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest";
const mockGetRecord = require("./data/users.json");
const getRecordWireAdapter = registerLdsTestWireAdapter(getUsers);

describe("c-data-table-dragable", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
    while (document.body.firstChild) {
      document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);

      // Prevent data saved on mocks from leaking between tests
      jest.clearAllMocks();
    }
  });

it("Check if data is loaded or not", () => {
    const element = createElement("c-data-table-dragable", {
      is: DataTableDragable
    });
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    getRecordWireAdapter.emit(mockGetRecord);
 
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      expect(element).toBeAccessible();
      //expect(element.users.data).toBe(mockGetRecord) //--giving error : cannot read property data of undefined.
      //expect(element.users.error).toBeUndefined()//--giving error : cannot read proper error of undefined.

      //however, the below code is working fine means it's rendering on HTML part. 
      const trEls = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('tr');
      expect(trEls.length).toBeGreaterThan(mockGetRecord.length);
    });
  });
```

mock file -

```json
[{
    "Id": "0050U000004YzSVQA0",
    "Username": "autoproc@00d0u000000gvvruac",
    "Email": "autoproc@00d0u000000gvvruac",
    "index": 0
}, {
    "Id": "0050U000004YzSaQAK",
    "Username": "automatedclean@00d0u000000gvvruac",
    "Email": "automatedclean@00d0u000000gvvruac",
    "index": 1
}, {
    "Id": "0050U000004YzSPQA0",
    "Username": "test-ofnikchfgnjt@example.com",
    "Email": "random.email@random.time",
    "index": 2
}, {
    "Id": "0050U000004YzSUQA0",
    "Username": "integration@00d0u000000gvvruac.com",
    "Email": "integration@example.com",
    "index": 3
}, {
    "Id": "0050U000004YzSYQA0",
    "Username": "insightssecurity@00d0u000000gvvruac.com",
    "Email": "insightssecurity@example.com",
    "index": 4
}, {
    "Id": "0050U000004YzSZQA0",
    "Username": "chatty.00d0u000000gvvruac.f9lyy22pvr2b@chatter.salesforce.com",
    "Email": "noreply@chatter.salesforce.com",
    "index": 5
}]
```

Comment: Please add the detail of your mockGetRecord.

Comment: @PhilW updated the mock data and its importing details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you can access only `@api` properties in the jest test context.

Everything that is marked `@track` or the `@wire` is going to be not defined in the test context.

You should just test the DOM elements that have rendered fine with the proper number of elements instead.

Comment: Hi Mohit, I tried giving track decorator to another variable(which is a map) and try to read in the jest, still it's giving undefined for that. can you point me to any recipe which is using that so that I can try that?

Comment: You need @api to access them! Track and wire won't be accessible! You query the dom elements for the same!